# styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular13

I am getting errors while I run ng serve on a web pack project which I convert from non-webpack.

Non-webpack was working fine.

This is the error I am getting

```
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
```

[image]

I check the other answers in StackOverflow. None of them are fixing my issue.

The change which I made in the project is to move the project to a different project structure

Previously the project was the below project structure

[image: Previus Project Structure]

But now I am in the current project structure.
[image: Current project structure]

The one highlighted in the above pic, there was my old project. In addition to this, I added another project called "project-list" which is also having the same error in the browser while I run.